# Ember-cli generate integration test for components as default

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have a project that was version 0.2.7 and generating component tests as unit tests. My new projects create integration tests by default. Is there a way to change it over?

Answer (score 6):

This is the default behavior now and as far as I know, can't be overwritten, as components should be run in isolation.  However, you can simply generate a unit test with:

```
ember g component-test your-component -unit
```

If you want to read up on why you should try integration tests, I found this article helpful:
http://alisdair.mcdiarmid.org/ember-component-integration-tests/

Comment: What if the current default is actually doing unit and i want integration?

Comment: You should update your version of Ember-CLI, as older versions really didn't have good integration testing for components.

Comment: I have been using the latest but there must be something in the config or something needs to be triggered (set) that didnt exist in the init of projects with older ember-cli that does now. Any ideas?